# Piecemaker fallback

Tags: jquery, flash, fallback

I was wondering if there is a way to include a fallback functionality for Piecemaker, so when a website is viewed on mobile, the page falls back to using a javascript based slider.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found a way around this by following crayon1's vein of thought and changing how it embeds the flash so that fallback child html can be included. This requires changing two files:

JavaScriptFlashGateway.js &

piecemaker-main.php
(Assuming we're talking about the WordPress plugin)

In JavaScriptFlashGateway.js, find this code:

```
function FlashTag(src, width, height)
{
    this.src       = src;
    this.width     = width;
    this.height    = height;
    this.version   = '9,0,0';
    this.id        = null;
    this.salign = "tl";
    this.scale = "noscale";
    this.allowScriptAccess = "always";
    this.allowfullscreen = "true";
    this.bgcolor   = 'ffffff';
    this.flashVars = null;
    this.wmode     = null;
}
```

And change it to this:

```
function FlashTag(src, width, height, fallback)
{
    this.src       = src;
    this.width     = width;
    this.height    = height;
    this.fallback  = fallback;
    this.version   = '9,0,0';
    this.id        = null;
    this.salign = "tl";
    this.scale = "noscale";
    this.allowScriptAccess = "always";
    this.allowfullscreen = "true";
    this.bgcolor   = 'ffffff';
    this.flashVars = null;
    this.wmode     = null;
}
```

Then further down find this line: "FlashTag.prototype.toString = function()"

And replace that entire function with this:

```
FlashTag.prototype.toString = function()
{
    var ie = (navigator.appName.indexOf ("Microsoft") != -1) ? 1 : 0;
    var flashTag = new String();
    flashTag += '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" ';
    if (this.id != null)
    {
        flashTag += 'id="'+this.id+'" ';
    }
    flashTag += 'codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version='+this.version+'" ';
    flashTag += 'width="'+this.width+'" ';
    flashTag += 'height="'+this.height+'">';
    flashTag += '<param name="movie" value="'+this.src+'"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="quality" value="high"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="bgcolor" value="#'+this.bgcolor+'"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="scale" value="noscale"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="salign" value="tl"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>';
    flashTag += '<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>';
    if (this.flashVars != null)
    {
        flashTag += '<param name="flashvars" value="'+this.flashVars+'"/>';
    }
    if(!ie) {
        flashTag += '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ';
        flashTag += 'data="'+this.src+'" ';
        flashTag += 'width="'+this.width+'" ';
        flashTag += 'height="'+this.height+'">';
        flashTag += '<param name="movie" value="'+this.src+'"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="quality" value="high"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="bgcolor" value="#'+this.bgcolor+'"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="scale" value="noscale"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="salign" value="tl"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>';
        flashTag += '<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>';
        if (this.flashVars != null)
        {
            flashTag += '<param name="flashvars" value="'+this.flashVars+'"/>';
        }
    }
    flashTag += this.fallback;
    if(!ie) {
        flashTag += '</object>';
    }
    flashTag += '</object>';
    return flashTag;
}
```

Then in piecemaker-main.php, find this line: "var tag = new FlashTag('{$this->piecemakerSWF}', {$att['width']}+50, {$att['height']}+100, '9,0,0');"

And replace '9,0,0' with whatever fallback html you need.

Then you're set! Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to figure this out? I don't think Piecemaker has this option by default and I haven't seen a way to do this with javascript that 100% mimics the Flash effects of Piecemaker (yet).

There is probably a better way to do this, but the first thing that comes to mind is using a mobile browser detection code (there are several of these available.. not sure what coding language you prefer, but just do a quick Google search and you can find different options). Then you can display either a version of your page using Piecemaker as the default or, if the visitor is using a mobile browser, display a version with the javascript/jQuery slider of your choice.

**EDIT** Looks like this is a good alternative with some fallback for older browsers: http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/index4.html

Hope that helps!